# Timeseries chart with aggregation over overlapping intervals

Tags: looker-studio

My dataset is of the following form:

```
Start Date  End Date    Count Contact
2019-01-20  2019-05-10  50        A
2019-03-05  2019-06-07  20        A
2019-03-05  2019-06-07  20        B
....
```

I want a timeseries chart where the X axis is months, and the Y axis is the total count.

E.g.
The entries would be

```
Month TotalCount Contact
Jan     50          A
Jan      0          B
Feb     50          A
Feb      0          B
Mar     70          A
Mar     20          B
Apr     70          A
Apr     20          B
May     70          A
May     20          B
Jun     20          A
Jun     20          B
Jul      0          A
Jul      0          B
...
```

How can I achieve this in Data Studio? The data is coming from bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do that in Data Studio visually alone without manipulating your dataset first.

You could instead use a custom query to generate the a date range of month starts (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array) and then join all rows from your dataset where the month start or between your start date and end date.

Example code for your example

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT date('2019-01-20') start_date,  date('2019-05-10') end_date,  50 count, 'A' contact
UNION ALL SELECT date('2019-03-05'), date('2019-06-07'), 20, 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT date('2019-03-05'), date('2019-06-07'), 20, 'B'
), monthDates AS (

SELECT months FROM
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2019-01-01', '2019-07-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) months
), monthContact AS (

SELECT months, contact
FROM monthDates m
CROSS JOIN CTE
GROUP BY 1,2
)

SELECT months, ifnull(sum(count),0) count, m.contact
FROM monthContact m
LEFT JOIN CTE c ON m.months BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND m.contact = c.contact
GROUP BY 1,3
ORDER BY 1,3
```

Comment: I changed the a missing adding additional point of separation. Even if I could call generate_date_array, how would I join them? Could you please give an example of the join?

Comment: I've edited the answer. If you don't care about the 0 values you can shorten that by removing the cross join query